# How refresh token works and how last failed http request called again which gave 401...?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth-2.0

I am working with a `OAuth2` using `angularjs`. Now i got stuck in authentication with `OAuth` in which i am unable to resend last 401 api. Any Idea.

I am using [this](https://github.com/seegno/angular-oauth2) oauth2 repo.

Controller.js

```
app.controller('validate', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', 'fullname', '$http', '$timeout', '$cookies', 'OAuth', function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, fullname, $http, $timeout, $cookies, OAuth) {
OAuth.getAccessToken($scope.user).then( function successCallBack(response){
            $scope.response = response;
            if($scope.response.status == 200){
                console.log($scope.response.data);
                $scope.accessToken      = $scope.response.data.access_token;
                $scope.refreshToken     = $scope.response.data.refresh_token;

                localStorage.setItem("accessToken", $scope.accessToken);
                localStorage.setItem("refreshToken", $scope.refreshToken);

                var userId = response.headers('userid');
                console.log(userId);
                $cookies.put("userId", userId);
                window.location.href = 'user_profile.php';
            }
        }, function errorCallBack(response){
            console.log(response);
        });
}]);
```

app.js

```
app.config(['OAuthProvider', function(OAuthProvider) {
OAuthProvider.configure({
  baseUrl: 'http://testzone.xxxxxx.net/api/LoginTest/Login/web/',
  clientId: '123456789',
  clientSecret: 'otszh9nonaosok88gsswc8k4w8ww04s',
  grantPath: 'api/oauth2/token',
  revokePath: 'api/oauth2/revoke'
});
}]);

app.run(['$rootScope', '$window', 'OAuth', '$cookies', '$timeout', function($rootScope, $window, OAuth, $cookies, $timeout) {
$rootScope.$on('oauth:error', function(event, rejection) {

  // Ignore `invalid_grant` error - should be catched on `LoginController`.
  if ('invalid_token' === rejection.data.error || 'invalid_grant' === rejection.data.error || 'invalid_request' === rejection.data.error || 'invalid_client' === rejection.data.error || 'unauthorized_client' === rejection.data.error || 'unsupported_grant_type' === rejection.data.error) {
        $cookies.remove('userId');
        $timeout(function(){
            window.location.href = 'index.php';
        },200);
  }

  // Refresh token when a `invalid_token` error occurs.
  if ('expired_token' === rejection.data.error) {
      console.log(rejection);

      OAuth.getRefreshToken();

  }

  console.log(rejection);
  console.log(rejection.data.error);
  console.log(rejection.data.error_description);

  // Redirect to `/login` with the `error_reason`.
  //return $window.location.href = 'index.php';

});
}]);
```

Thanks

Comment: means you are getting `401 error:unauthorized error` while the first request, and you want to solve it now?

Comment: yes exactly after that refresh token called and now i want to request previous 401 http again...means i also want to know whole structure how token authentication works.

Comment: you want to know `api flow`, or how to generate `accesstoken` from `refreshtoken`?  nd to request previous no code is available in this post, how may one help you

Comment: I have edited the question. i hope it will help you to understand.

Comment: can you add stacktrace ?

Comment: I dont know what is stacktrace if its fiddle or type something, then its not possible to do that because this code consist authentication.

Comment: stacktrace in the sense, full error message, btw i edited my answer, i added one github project link in my answer, you can see that if you want.

Comment: mine and yours urls are same...phew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this when analysing the error response:

```
if (rejection.status === 401) {
    var authService = $injector.get('oAuthService');
    var authData = ipCookie(oAuthConstants.oAuthCookieName);
    var $http = $http || $injector.get('$http');
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    if (authData) {
        authService.refreshToken().then(function () {
            //this repeats the request with the original parameters
            return deferred.resolve($http(rejection.config));
        });
    }

    return deferred.promise;
}
else if (rejection.status === 403) {
    var toaster = $injector.get('toaster');
    toaster.pop('error', "Access Denied", "You are not authorized to do this request.");
}
else {
    return $q.reject(rejection);
}
```

The key to repeat the last 401 api call is:

```
return deferred.resolve($http(rejection.config));
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but still i need to add access Token as header which came from refreshToken() in new api which is repeating.

Comment: can you please tell how to resume code after getting refresh token.

Comment: Hi @Talhamansoor, execute `return deferred.resolve($http(rejection.config));` after getting the refresh token. Tell me if you need more pieces of code.

Answer (score 0):

- A `refresh token` is a special kind of `JWT` that is used to obtain a renewed `id_token` at any time.
- Refresh tokens carry the information necessary to get a new access token. In other words, whenever an access token is required to access a specific resource, a client may use a refresh token to get a new access token issued by the authentication server.

and how to use it in angular js see this link , [click here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth2-refresh-token-angular-js)
it will guide you how to do it.

---

see this related project, you can get idea from it. [github code](https://github.com/oauthjs/angular-oauth2)

Comment: if you want something more than above answer, than reply me

Comment: The problem i am facing is that i am unable to send last 401 unauthorized request again.

Comment: A refresh token does not need to be a JWT. Actually most of the time, it's just a random string (a GUID for example) which is saved on the server.